# What is the meaning of "Projects tied to {node}" in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-2, jenkins-agent

I created a Jenkins node / agent / slave and use it for a pipeline. On the node's page there is a list "*Projects tied to mynode*". What does this mean? When is a project "*tied*" to a node?

Btw.: If "*tied to a project*" means here, that the node is *used in a project*, so why is this list empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Projects tired to ...." will list Freestyle jenkins job which restrict the job executed on this node by specify the node label in job's configuration field:

**Restrict where this project can be run -> Label Expression**

[image]

After you run the job, your job will appear in the "Projects tired to ...." list

I think this list purpose is to let user know the impacted jobs when the node down or before restart or repair the node.

FYI, if the node label filled in Label Expression serviced by more than one machine, the job won't appear in that list. Because job can be executed on any one machine in that group.

Comment: It's also beat practice to create labels based on specific node properties (eg: OS, installed tools, etc.), assign those labels to nodes,then use those labels instead of tieing directly to nodes. Today'you may have one corresponding node, but if you add more then you have to re-jig everything anyway!